# Add an entry to manifest file inside maven-jar-plugin using maven-ant-plugin

Tags: maven, ant, pom.xml

I am setting a property using maven-ant-plugin and I want that property inside maven-jar-plugin to be placed as a custom entry inside the jar's manifest file.
How can I achieve that ?

Update: Here is my pom file. I want the value of property "abc", which contains custom class-path to be added to the manifest file, in maven-jar-plugin.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-folder1-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <prefix>folder1</prefix>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/folder1/</outputDirectory>
                        <outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename>true</outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename>
                        <excludeGroupIds>package.folder1</excludeGroupIds>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-folder2-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <prefix>folder2</prefix>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/folder2/</outputDirectory>
                        <outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename>true</outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename>
                        <includeGroupIds>package.folder2</includeGroupIds>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>concat-build-classpath</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
                        <target>
                            <path id="master-classpath">
                                <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/folder1/">
                                    <include name="*.jar" />
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/folder2/">
                                    <include name="*.jar" />
                                </fileset>
                            </path>

                            <property name="absolute-path" value="${toString:master-classpath}" />

                            <loadresource property="relative-path">
                                <propertyresource name="absolute-path" />
                                <filterchain>
                                    <tokenfilter>
                                        <filetokenizer/>
                                        <replaceregex pattern="(^.*?target\\|(?&lt;=;).*?target\\)"
                                            replace="" flags="g" />
                                        <replaceregex pattern="(\\)" replace="/" flags="g" />
                                        <replaceregex pattern="(folder1)"
                                            replace="../folder1" flags="g" />
                                    </tokenfilter>
                                </filterchain>
                            </loadresource>

                            <property name="abc" value="${relative-path}"/>

                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>include-path-in-jar</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Class-path>${abc}</Class-path>>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why are you doing so int maven-ant-plugin instead of [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html) ?

Comment: @Khmarbaise the classpath attribute of the manifest file lists all the dependent jars of the project. I want to append some of the jar names with folder1/<jarname.jar> and some with folder2/<jarname.jar>. I am setting a property inside maven ant plugin which contains the desired output as its value. I am planning of using that value inside maven jar plugin's manifestentries tag.

Comment: Apart from that it sounds like you would like to create an executable jar which means you should either use maven-assembly-plugin (jar-with-dependencies) or you should use maven-shade-plugin to create such thing which contains also all dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

If you like to add the classpath there is a configuration for doing so:

```xml
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    ...
```

Comment: I tried that already. I have added my pom file and edited my question to make it clearer.